# hide p element if empty

Tags: jquery, hidden

I want to use jQuery to hide a p element with class of .last_edit if the p element is empty. example

```
<p class="last_edit"></p>

<p class="last_edit">This would be displayed since there is text in it</p>
```

Does anyone know how t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways

```
$(".last_edit:empty").hide();
```

or

```
$(".last_edit").each(function() {

    if($.trim($(this).html()).length > 0) {
       $(this).hide();
    }

});
```

Comment: If there is one empty `.last_edit` element hide all the elements with class of `last_edit`?

Comment: it will hide all element with class 'last_edit' if the element is empty

Comment: @Starx i just explaining to undefined what your first solution will do :)

Comment: Thanks starx! worked like a charm, liked the first code, lot cleaner to me lol. Thanks

Comment: @undefined it seemed, you did! if not, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can hide it with CSS like this:

```
.last_edit:empty {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:empty` selector:

```
$('p.last_edit:empty').hide();
```

or `filter` method:

```
$('p.last_edit').filter(function(){
     return $.trim($(this).text()) === ''
}).hide()
```